# Meeting Room Reservation permission logic realization

Tags: development, permissions

I'm new to SP. I need to create Meeting Room Reservation webpart. I have two rooms so that users can select the appropriate one and create a new event in calendar. At the initial step when user creates event there will be new item add permissions. Next step is approval of the request by department head. Department head must have item edit/delete permissions. So everything is ok, but there one problem appears: department head can edit and delete the item which is not related to his department, for example user in departmentA has created new event, but head of departmentB could edit/delete this event, it is wrong because only head of departmentA can edit/delete that event. I don't know how to differentiate such kind of permissions. Any thoughts?

Answer (score 0):

You can add ListItemEventReceiver and in ItemDeleting event check if event related to user's department. If the department is wrong then cancel deleting and show error message to user.

[How to: Create an Event Receiver - MSDN](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ee231563.aspx)